# Multiprocessing queue to get the data to handle for process

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I have a list with filenames of files need to extract and I have a function which extracts these files. And since it is mostly CPU using task, it would be nice to spawn it between multiple processes to utilize multiple CPU-s.

Right now my code looks like this:

```
import multiprocessing

def unpack(files):
  for f in files:
     Archive(f).extractall('\\path\\to\\destination\\')


n_cpu = multiprocessing.cpu_count()
chunks = split(cabs_to_unpack, n_cpu) # just splits array into n equal chunks

for i in range(n_cpu):
    p = Process(target=unpack, args=(chunks[i],))
    p.start()
    p.join()
```

But files to handle are very different by size. Some files are 1 kb, most are something about 300 kb and a few files are about 1.5Gb.

So my approach works not perfect: 5 processes handle their portion files very fast and exiting, and other three processes are working hard to handle some large file and a bunch of small files. So it wold be nice to make fast processes not to exit, but handle these small files too.

And it looks like it would be nice to use here some Queue with list of files, which can work correct with multiple processes. And my unpack function would looks like this:

```
def unpack(queue):
  while queue.not_empty():
     f = queue.get()
     Archive(f).extractall('\\path\\to\\destination\\')
```

But I can't find this Queue in multiprocessing module. The only multiprocessing .Queue doesn't take a list of objects to initialize and looks like it should be used as a container where processes push the data and not as a container to get data from.

So my question is simple and maybe stupid (I'm new to multiprocessing), but which object/class should I use as a container with data to handle?

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend a [`multiprocessing.Pool`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.pool.Pool).

```
from multiprocessing import Pool

def unpack(file_path):
    Archive(file_path).extractall('\\path\\to\\destination\\')

pool = Pool()
pool.map(unpack, list_of_files)
```

It already deals with chunk size, re-use of the worker processes and process handling logic.